# Who Invented DRADIS?

Tags: history-of, battlestar-galactica, props, battlestar-galactica-2004

As the question implies: in the BSG (Battlestar Galactica) reimagined universe, is it ever mentioned in-universe the background of DRADIS (Direction, RAnge, and DIStance) and who invented it? I’m talking books or comics. I don’t think the series or films ever did.

It’s an instrument that holds a fairly central role and ambient effect in the series. The familiar rhythmic whine of the array and the rings swirling around each other as they plot targets on the spherical map on the HUDs on a Raptor or Viper, or in the CIC (Combat Information Center) screen hub above the command console.

Comment: I don't think we'll ever find out who the Frak invented it

Comment: And what, exactly, is the difference between RAnge and DIStance?  Personally I think this is a backronym and it was invented by Mary Dradis.

Comment: RAnge might be weapons ranges